# check/ wait to receive messages in websoket

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, websocket, wait

I'm trying to create a script that waits for a Boolean variable to become true and logs a text to console. The following code will wait for s1 and then print a message to the console when the variable is true.

```
while(s1 === false) {}
console.log("s1");
```

The s1 variable is set using the websocket's onmessage. The following code will set the variable and initialize the websocket

```
// initializing the websocket
conn = {}, window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
openConnection();
s1 = false;

function openConnection() {

// uses global 'conn' object
if (conn.readyState === undefined || conn.readyState > 1) {
    conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8100');

    conn.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (event.data == "S1")
            s1 = true;
        else if (event.data == "S2")
            s2 = true;
        else if (event.data == "S3")
            s3 = true;

        console.log(s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
        };

    }
}
}
```

The code should work great but since javascript is a one threaded language the variable s1 is never updated. until the while loop is done.

I have tried using workers but I need to change DOM and access global variables which is a limit with workers. Moreover timing is really important in this script.

I was wondering is there a way for me to check if there are any massages queued to be received by onmessage and wait until they are received? or can I do a overall check for any queued tasks while I'm doing a loop?

Thank you :)

Comment: don't use _while_ for that, ever. can't you do what you need when it changes from inside the onmessage event?

Comment: look into EventEmitters so you can easily couple these un-connected happenings.